# cg_annotate and callgrind_annotate is showing "no information has been collected for Sourcefile" in ubuntu

Tags: valgrind

I am new to the Valgrind tool and I am using my cross compiled valgrind with ARM target board to run my executable.
While executing the  cachegrind tool with my executable it successfully generating the cachegrind.out.PID file as like below

## ] /opt/valgrind/bin/valgrind --tool=cachegrind ./w-rpc

file that generated out of it is in the name of cachegrind.out.29271.

Since my target board doesn't have perl support, I could not able to run cg_annotate in my target board. So I am  running this cg_annotate file with this cachegrind.out.29271 at my **ubuntu** machine. But every time it is showing this below information only. I cannot see the detailed source code analysis information, is that problem of version mismatch or anything I am missing here. Please suggest me a solution for this, I am really blocked on this situation and tried almost all possible solution which is available on the valgrind documentation.

below is the information that i could able to see from the cachegrind.out.29271 file and at the end of this report it saying "No information has been collected for /home/radhar/myshare/PB_Test/c_RPCMonitor.cc ",please see the below

```
$  cg_annotate   cachegrind.out.29271 /home/radhar/myshare/PB_Test/c_RPCMonitor.cc

I1 cache:         16384 B, 64 B, 4-way associative
D1 cache:         16384 B, 64 B, 4-way associative
LL cache:         262144 B, 64 B, 8-way associative
Command:          ./w-rpc_exit
Data file:        cachegrind.out.29271
Events recorded:  Ir I1mr ILmr Dr D1mr DLmr Dw D1mw DLmw
Events shown:     Ir I1mr ILmr Dr D1mr DLmr Dw D1mw DLmw
Event sort order: Ir I1mr ILmr Dr D1mr DLmr Dw D1mw DLmw
Thresholds:       99 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
Include dirs:     
User annotated:   /home/radhar/myshare/PB_Test/c_RPCMonitor.cc 
Auto-annotation:  off 

Ir   I1mr  ILmr        Dr    D1mr   DLmr        Dw  D1mw  DLmw 

38,385,638 14,462 4,450 5,369,475 159,757 63,018 1,424,411 2,155 1,337  PROGRAM TOTALS 

Ir  I1mr  ILmr        Dr   D1mr   DLmr      Dw D1mw DLmw  file:function 

26,263,438   238    23 1,398,703 59,346 15,533 237,160   30   13  ???:_dl_lookup_hash 
 9,128,805 6,745 2,174 2,919,360 92,571 43,596 511,921  776  396  ???:??? 
   320,759    58    12   105,071    108      0  72,599    2    0  ???:pthread_mutex_unlock 
   293,044   493    10    91,275    252     13  86,395   26    3  ???:pthread_mutex_lock 
   232,047    33     2   122,130     47      0  36,639    0    0  ???:OMTimerManager::lock() const 
   232,028    27     2   122,120      0      0  36,636    0    0  ???:OMTimerManager::unlock() const 
   185,511    24     2    68,015     37      2  68,018    0    0  ???:pthread_setcanceltype 
   164,862    88     4    48,848      0      0  24,424    0    0  ???:OMTimerManager::post() 
   146,544    47     3    73,272      0      0  24,424    0    0  ???:OMTimerManager::timeTickCbk() 
   134,355    73     5    67,171     18      0  61,074    0    0  ???:nanosleep 
   122,150    14     0    36,645      0      0  36,645    0    0  ???:LinuxMutex::unlock() 
   122,150    12     1    36,645      0      0  36,645    0    0  ???:LinuxMutex::lock() 
   100,373    41    40     3,903     15     10  16,463  235  234  ???:_dl_load_elf_shared_library 
    97,252   875    55    28,280    566     37  12,461  518  371  ???:malloc 
    91,605    25     3    24,426     31      0       3    0    0  ???:LinuxTimer::waitThread() 
    79,391    35     2    18,321      0      0  12,214    0    0  ???:OMUHeap::isEmpty() const 
    67,166    37     1    30,530     50      2   6,106    0    0  ???:OMThread::isEndOfProcess() 
    55,240     0     0         0      0      0  13,810    1    0  ???:__pthread_unlock 
    54,954    37     2    18,318      0      0  18,318    0    0  ???:OMTimerManager::cbkBridge(void*) 
    35,557     6     6    11,905  2,079  2,050   5,948    5    5  ???:_dl_fixup 
    27,620    17     6         0      0      0       0    0    0  ???:__pthread_lock 
    26,996     4     2    14,292      0      0   9,528    2    0  ???:_pthread_cleanup_pop_restore 
    25,552   162    18    12,865    117     16   7,883    8    0  ???:free 

User-annotated source: /home/radhar/myshare/PB_Test/c_RPCMonitor.cc 

No information has been collected for /home/radhar/myshare/PB_Test/c_RPCMonitor.cc
```

Exactly I need to see the detailed analysis report of the source file (which consists of many functions)...?

Thanks In advance for your time and help,

Ratheesh

Comment: Have you seen: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18944716/cachegrinds-cg-annotate-does-not-display-annotation-for-my-source-code